# How to get maxHorizontalScrollPosition in Spark list component

Tags: list, apache-flex, flex-spark

I want to get maxHorizontalScrollPosition for Spark list control.
Please let me know if there is any alternative propperty for it in flex 4

Comment: I'm guessing; but would contentHeight on the list's dataGroup give you the value you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
idList.horizontalScrollBar.maxScrollPosition
```

Hope that works!